# stream was reset: HTTP_1_1_REQUIRED Error Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am facing strange error with all "GET" Api's in Lollipop and above devices where as it works well with kitkat devices.Also all POST Api's are working fine.When ever I am requesting it fails with `java.io.IOException: stream was reset: HTTP_1_1_REQUIRED'`.

Answer (score 4):

in OkHttp add this line in builder

```
.protocols(Util.immutableList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1))
```

like this

```
 private OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .protocols(Util.immutableList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1))
            .build();
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're requiring client certificates for specific resources? These are not supported in HTTP/2, as they require renegotiation after sending the connection prefix. The stream will be reset as a result, and the user-agent should retry with HTTP/1.1.

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same problem as you, in my case the problem is with the SSL Cert of my local server that I use to test my App, so changing the base URL of the API to `http://domain...` instead of `https://domain...` solves my problem.

Now I need to figure out why my SSL Cert (Let's encrypt) in my local server (IIS) causes this problem in Android 5.0+.

I Hope this helps you to solve your problem, at least as a start point. Would be great if anyone else helps to solve the problem with the SSL Cert.

Answer (score 0):

If you use okHttp 4.2.2 with interceptors, try replace `.addNetworkInterceptor()` with `.addInterceptor()` in OkHttpClient.Builder(), it helps me with same error occuring in authenticator.